# vim in cygwin some strange underline,how can fix this?

Tags: vim, cygwin, underline

[image]
[image]

i am use cygwin on windows7, syntax on in ~/.vimrc.

when i try to write a test shell file,there are so much underline,it's boring,how can i get rid of it?i try let html_no_rendering=1 ,but it doesn't work here,and these file is not html file .

here is my ~/.vimrc:

```
set nu
hi LineNr       term=NONE cterm=NONE
set ts=4
set fenc=4
set fencs=utf-8,usc-bom,euc-jp,gb18030,gbk,gb2312,cp936
set nocp
set ai
set si
if &term != "cygwin"
    set ruler
endif
set incsearch
set showmatch
set backspace=indent,eol,start
syntax on
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set encoding=utf8
set fileencodings=utf8,gbk


set nocompatible 
set history=50 
set autoindent 
set smartindent 
set showmatch 
set showcmd
set wildmenu
set fo=cqrt
set laststatus=2
set textwidth=78
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set nobackup
```

Comment: What colorscheme are you using? Each colorscheme is special. For example if you use [Solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) you can put `let g:solarized_underline=0` in your .vimrc file and it will not use any kind of underline. Basically it all depends on the theme you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlines are defined in your colorscheme. Open it and search for the word `underline`. You can change that value to:

```
bold
undercurl
reverse
inverse
italic
standout
NONE
```